# Auto capture video using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I'm working on this piece of code responsible for starting video recording on button click.
When I click the button camera view is opening but .startVideoCapture() function doesn't start recording.

I get this strange output every time button is pressed:

> 2015-08-19 16:48:09.588 Record Video With Swift[922:227442]
>   Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Also, is there any way to hide the camera view and instead of it place there some progress bar or something?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate 
    {

       let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
       var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
       var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
 {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        println("captureVideoPressed and camera available.")
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie!]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
    }

    else 
    {
        println("Camera not available.")
    }
}

@IBAction func rec(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    imagePicker.startVideoCapture()
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) 
    {
    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
    let pathString = tempImage.relativePath
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathString, self, nil, nil)
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem and in my case I was using Swift 3 with iOS 10. There are couple of ways to solve it:

You can call the startVideoCapture() in the completion block of present viewcontroller as following:

```
self.present(self.cameraController, animated: true, completion: {
    self.cameraController.startVideoCapture()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false) { _ in
            self.stopMovementsCapture()
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5,
                             target: self,
                             selector: #selector(self.stopMovementsCapture),
                             userInfo: nil,
                             repeats: false)
    }
})
```

Another way to do is, is by calling startVideoCapture() only after the AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunning notification is fired.

Following is the code to observe the notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.cameraIsReady), name: .AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunning, object: nil)
```

Following is function called by the above notification:

```
func cameraIsReady(notification: NSNotification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cameraController.startVideoCapture()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false) { _ in
                self.stopMovementsCapture()
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.stopMovementsCapture),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically make sure that your device is ready to capture the video. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following:

1.

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = NSArray(object: kUTTypeMovie)  as! [String]
```

2.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
    let pathString = tempImage.relativePath

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathString!, self, nil, nil)

}
```